# Passing 2d Arrays by Reference in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have been searching and reading for a while now and I can not see why this will not work.

I am passing a 2d array using the `&` to pass the address of the first location in memory. The function accepts a `char *tokens` a pointer to that memory location.

The function:

```
void printOutput( FILE* template, char* tokens)
{
    char c = fgetc(template);

    while(c != EOF )
    {
        if( c != '$' )
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        else
        {
            c = fgetc(template);
            int charVal = c-'0';

            if( charVal >= 0 && charVal <= 9 )
            {
                printf("%d" , charVal);
                printf("%s" , tokens[charVal]);
            }
        }
        c = fgetc(template);
    }
   printf("\n\n");
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
printOutput(template, &tokens[0]);
```

If I put the function code into the main function in place of the `printOutput` function call, the output is properly displayed.

From what I can tell is that somewhere between the function call and the function running something is happening that turns my `tokens[][]` into an array of all `(null)`.

I believe I am address it incorrectly and hope someone can help. I can also provide more code if needed.

I really appreciate any help!

Due to answers helping, but still not solving the issue, I am resorting to adding the `main()` function from my code.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
FILE *template = NULL;
FILE *data = NULL;

char input[INPUT_LENGTH];

template = fopen( "template.txt", "r" );
if ( template != NULL )
{
    data = fopen( "data.txt", "r" );
    if ( data != NULL )
    {

        char input[INPUT_LENGTH];

        while ( fgets(input, INPUT_LENGTH, data) )
        {
            char *token = NULL;
            char *tokens[INPUT_LENGTH][FIELD_LENGTH];

            int pos = 0;
            token = strtok(input, "|");
            while(token != NULL )
            {
                tokens[pos][0] = token;
                token = strtok(NULL, "|");
                pos++;
            }

            printOutput(template, tokens[INPUT_LENGTH][FIELD_LENGTH]);

            rewind(template);
        }

        fclose( data );
    }

    fclose( template );
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

I can only now assume the issue has to do with the `char *tokens[INPUT_LENGTH][FIELD_LENGTH];` declaration, but I am totally unsure at this point.

Comment: What is the type of `tokens` at the call site?

Comment: fgetc() actually returns an int.   EOF is an int.  so comparing a char to an int will not work properly.   Suggest changing 'char c' to 'int c'

Comment: the posted code is inconsistent about which char in the file is being read by each fgetc().  suggest controlling the loop by 'while( EOF != (c= fgetc(template) )'  and removing all the other calls to fgetc()

Answer (score 5):

Your 2D array `char tokens[X][LEN]` is laid out in memory as:

```
Value     : Mem addresses for char[LEN]

tokens[0] :         0 . . . LEN-1
tokens[1] :       LEN . . . 2*LEN-1
tokens[X-1] : (X-1)*LEN . . . X*LEN - 1
```

Conversely, `char* tokens` is interpreted as:

```
Value     : Mem addresses for char

tokens[0] : 0
tokens[1] : 1
tokens[2] : 2
```

Now, when you pass these to `printf` with a string format, you're dereferencing the value to a `char`, not a `char*` like it expects.  Hence the bad output / undefined behaviour.

Even if you took the address (`printf("%s" , &tokens[charVal]);`), it would still not give you your expected result because it's resolving to the wrong address.

Since your 2D array has a fixed size, you should declare the function like this:

```
void printOutput( FILE* template, char tokens[X][LEN] )
```

Where `X` and `LEN` are the two array dimensions, obviously...  In case it wasn't clear after my prolific use of them above =)

This way, the compiler knows exactly how to interpret `tokens[charVal]`, which will be an array type that decays to a `char*`.

---

[Edit, since you provided more information and code]

You are still getting confused between `char*` and `char` with your arrays.  I've corrected this, as `tokens` should be a one-dimensional array of `char*`.

```
        char *tokens[INPUT_LENGTH] = { 0 };

        int pos = 0;
        token = strtok(input, "|");
        while(token != NULL )
        {
            tokens[pos] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            pos++;
        }

        printOutput(template, tokens);
```

Also, `printOutput` should be defined as:

```
void printOutput( FILE* template, char** tokens)
```

Comment: this starts to solve the problem, but the tokens[][] still contains null values. I am going to edit to include main.

Comment: I have edited my answer, since you have supplied code.  There may be other problems with your program.  I've just addressed the immediately obvious ones.

Answer (score 1):

From the following printf statement inside printOutput (), I believe you are trying to access tokens as if it is an array of strings. 
    printf("%s" , tokens[charVal]);

But you have declared tokens as just a char pointer in printOutput (), which can at best only stand-in for an array of characters (or in other words just 1 string if it is null terminated).

Either you need to declare it as a double dimension array

```
void printOutput (FILE* template, char tokens[MAX_STRINGS] [MAX_CHARS_IN_STRING])
```

Or declare it as a pointer to array of characters

```
void printOutput (FILE* template, char (*tokens) [MAX_CHARS_IN_STRING])
```

and call it as

```
printOutput(template, tokens);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are passing tokens as a 'char *', however, what you are trying to do, is to pass a 'char **', namely, a pointer to a pointer that points to the first element of your 2D array.

Try this:

```
void printOutput( FILE* template, char** tokens)
```

And call it as follows:

```
printOutput(template, tokens);
```

Note that you want all 'char *' in tokens to have a '\0' terminator.

e.g. tokens[0] = {'a','b','c','\0'} or tokens[0] = "abc"
since printf won't know where to stop printing '%s'otherwise

Comment: A `char**` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. It is not the pointer to a "2D" char array. The latter would look like this: `char (*p)[x][y]`.